# block a thread until it gets a specific signal from some other thread (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

I have an java server application communicating with clients via sockets. Every client request is handled in a new thread. But for some requests I need to synchronize two clients.

Example:

- Client A sends a request to the Server S.
- Thread S1 on S accepts the request of A.
- S1 informs Client B about this request (via GoogleCloudMessaging).
- S1 SHOULD BLOCK NOW
- Client B receives the information from S and sends a request to S.
- Thread S2 on S accepts the request of B.
- S1 SHOULD BE RELEASED NOW and get the message from S2
- S1 sends the answer to Client A

I know about the Lock Condition mechanism, but this does not work here, because I don't know the condition when creating the threads. I need something like:

```
// Pseudo Code
// on the S1 Thread, first argument beeing a signal ID, second a timeout
s1.waitForSignal("clientB", 10000);
// and on the S2 Thread to continue S1
SignalSender.send("clientB");
```

Is anything like this possible in Java? Is there any other solution for my problem?

Comment: yes, there are wait & notify methods. try using them.

Comment: No, *don't use wait and notify*. They are a relic of the past and new code should not use it. Use an appropriate synchronizing aid from `java.util.concurrent`, such as `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Thanks, I like the pizza example. But with wait & notify I still need an instance of the waiting object in both threads, don't I? Because I don't know which thread has to wait for or notify which thread on creation. I first know this when parsing the message from the socket (or maybe when getting the SSLSession object).

Comment: @user2564801 It looks like you're walking down a potential path of deadlocks. Consider the potential case where all threads in the threadpool of S are taken by client As who are waiting for B to connect. B cannot connect because there are no threads remaining in the thread pool to accept connections, and A will never continue until it receives a message from B. Be sure you have some sort of timeout logic somewhere down the chain (even if Tomcat handles timeouts for you).

Comment: The CountDownLatch seems to be nice, too. But I still need to somehow pass the CountDownLatch object to my other thread on its runtime. How do I do this? Some sort of global synchronized HashMap?

Comment: @Colin Morelli: I want to have a timeout as shown in the pseudo code. And besides that can each client have only one server connection (equals one server thread) at a time.

Comment: @user2564801 First of all, where is the restriction that each client can only have one server connection? Did you write that? Because that's not standard. Secondly, it wouldn't matter, as multiple clients can each have one connection and still wind up in deadlocks. But I did miss your timeout in the pseudo code, so I apologize for that. The warning still stands though

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you do not have a shared reference on which you could invoke `wait`/`notify` (not to mention a shared lock condition that you could use).

Well, first of all there is stuff shared between those two threads already: namely, in your case, the string `"ClientB"`. If you have this, all you need to do is map that string to a single reference in a place that is accessible by both classes.

The simplest implementation would be to hold a static map field somewhere and just fill it with monitor objects somehow:

```
public final class Monitors {

    private Monitors() {}

    private static final Map<String, Object> monitors = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    static { monitors.put("ClientB", new Object()); }

    public static Object get(String key) { return monitors.get(key); }

}
```

Of course, you may want to write a proper service that manages this mapping and perhaps uses locks and conditions internally. Also, a good idea would be to encapsulate the waiting and signaling functionality within the service itself and then use it like: `monitorService.waitForSignalsFrom("ClientB")`.

Comment: So your answer was really a statement of exactly what you think the OP _shouldn't_ do? :)

Comment: Not really: I pointed out a solution; the actual implementation is just too simplistic to be used as such. But you're right, that warning in the end kind of messes all up: I'll edit :)

Comment: I was just giving you a hard time. It doesn't seem like there is a very clean solution to this problem (that could be answered in a SO answer).

Comment: So it might work like this: http://pastebin.com/a9b3pLAS ? I would synchronize the Threads via CountDownLatch (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), but handle the CountDownLatch objects in a global synchronized Map object?

Comment: Let's just say you encapsulate that functionality in a shared component (some service) -- just to make this sound better. Of course, there's room for improvement in both the interface and implementation: for the interface, I would rather not return the CDLs but perform the operations on them internally. For the implementation, you should consider using a `ConcurrentMap`...

Comment: However, the whole point I was trying to make is that you need to identify what is common in both places and start from there: if all you have is a common string value, you need to map that to something useful.